# I have two exponential functions, how can I generate any exponential function within the range of the two functions?

Tags: python, math, random, curve-fitting, polynomials

I have two exponential function like: A1(1/λ)^k1, and A2(1/λ)^k2
how can I find any exponential function within the range of the two functions?
The function we need also follow this form. For example: Ax(1/λ)^kx, which Ax and kx are the value I want to know.

[image]

Here is my pseudo code:

```
def fun_random_gen(fun_upper_bound, fun_lower_bound)
    generate Ax(1/λ)^kx within fun_upper_bound, fun_lower_bound
    return Ax, kx
```

Appreciate !

If I use the linear combination of upper bound and lower bound, I could't generate this kind of curve : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL6rD.jpg)

Also I tried to generate Ax in [A1,A2] and kx in [k1,k2] randomly, and then I limited the generated curve not exceed the upper and lower bounds. However I need a long long time to generate one curve.

Comment: Surely if you find `Ax = (A1+A2)/2` and `kx=(k1+k2)/2`, you will have an answer.  I think algebra guarantees that.  Indeed, `(A1*alpha + A2*(1-alpha))` (and same for `k`) for any alpha in (0.0,1.0) should work.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I didn’t mention before, λ is bounded in [700,880], which means the generated function can be more sloped or flatter than the upper bound and lower bound.

Comment: I don't know what that means.  For a given lambda, what I'm saying is correct.  If lambda is a variable, then there is no answer.

Comment: Sure what you say was right. Sorry for my bad explaination, I edited my article above.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Roberts mentioned, you can use algebra to define such function and generate from it.

If you would like1. to have a different function any time (under the constraints of the exponential family)- generate alpha and k as Tim mentioned.

Assuming you don't have the algebraic function and only a pythonic function-
You may generate some Xs, use the parameter functions (fun_upper_bound, fun_lower_bound) and then use a linear combination between them.

Example:

1. you generate an X
2. upper_val = fun_upper_bound(X)
3. lower_val = fun_lower_bound(X)
4. generate alpha (between[0.0,1.0])
5. return alpha*upper_val + (1-alpha)*lower_val